# Shuffle an array in PHP

Tags: php, shuffle

I have the following code:

```
<?php
foreach($bb['slides'] as $b):
$url = "domain.com/" . $b->image . ";
echo($url);
endforeach;
?>
```

The output is as follows:
domain.com/image1.jpg
domain.com/image2.jpg
domain.com/image3.jpg

I am trying to randomize the order of the output. Before the foreach statement I tried to shuffle the array using shuffle($bb); but that did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did your code look like with shuffle?  It should have worked.  maybe with a sample set of 3, you just happened to be unlucky and it shuffled back into the same order.  Did you do a shuffle($bb) or shuffle($bb['slides'])?

Comment: Should it be shuffle($bb['slides'])?

Comment: My implementation with mt_rand better than shuffle() http://stackoverflow.com/a/43532529/960020

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As $bb is an array of arrays, shuffle() won't randomise the sub-array, try `shuffle` on the nested array as follows:

```
shuffle($bb['slides']);
```

Comment: It returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. But if you dump the array after the shuffle it will be shuffled,

Answer (score 2):

You probably shuffled the outer $bb array, when you should have done:

```
shuffle($bb['slides']);
foreach($bb['slides'] as $b):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
shuffle($array_name); // will shuffle array
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Also the foreach should be

```
for($array_name as $array_item) {
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: His foreach loop looks correct. Err...aside from the colon. :)

Comment: @New Guy - You're right if $bb['slides'] is an array. To me it appeared that he was accessing a single element ('slides') and attempting to foreach that instead. I.e. I thought $bb was the array he was attempting to loop.

Comment: And actually his colon is correct too. Didn't notice he was using the alternative syntax for control structures. Don't see that very often anymore.

Comment: @New Guy - You're right, there is nothing wrong with : syntax, my foreach loop was to emphasize the outer vs inner loop. The braces simply came from habit

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
shuffle($bb['slides']);
foreach($bb['slides'] as $b) {
    echo $url = "domain.com/" . $b->image . ";
}
?>
```

Check this blog for explanation with example.

http://wamp6.com/php/str_shuffle-php/ [Check for array shuffle](http://wamp6.com/php/array-shuffle-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to do `shuffle( $bb['slides'] )`.

Answer (score 0):

**Display content at random order**

```
<?php
$myContentList = array (
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
    'Four'
);
shuffle ($myContentList);
foreach ($myContentList as $displayAtRandomOrder) {
echo '<div>' . $displayAtRandomOrder . '</div>';
}
?>
```

**Display images at random order**

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
    'one.png',
    'two.png',
    'three.jpg',
    'four.gif'
);
shuffle ($myImagesList);
foreach ($myImagesList as $displayImagesAtRandomOrder) {
echo '<img src="images/' . $displayImagesAtRandomOrder . '" width="200" height="40" border="0" />';
}
?>
```