# How random is PHP's shuffle function?

Tags: php, random, shuffle

Does anyone know what's the randomness of PHP's `shuffle()` function? Does it depend on the operating system?
Does it use PHP's own seeder?

Is it possible to use `mt_rand()` as generator?

Comment: It's random enough for most applications. But it isn't cryptographically safe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`shuffle()` function is based on the same generator as `rand()`, which is the system generator based on [linear congruential algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). This is a fast generator, but with more or less randomness. Since PHP 4.2.0, the random generator is seeded automatically, but you can use `srand()` function to seed it if you want.

`mtrand()` is based on [Mersenne Twister algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), which is one of the best pseudo-random algorithms available. To shuffle an array using that generator, you'd need to write you own shuffle function. You can look for example at [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Writing you own shuffle function will yield to better randomness, but will be slower than the builtin shuffle function.

Answer (score 7):

### Update for PHP 7.1

Since the [rng_fixes rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/rng_fixes) was implemented for PHP 7.1, the implementation of `shuffle` now utilizes the Mersenne Twister PRNG (i.e. it uses `mt_rand` and is affected by calling `mt_srand`).

The legacy system PRNG (`rand`) is no longer available; the functions `rand` and `srand` are in fact aliased to their `mt_` equivalents.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Mirouf's answer (thank you so much for your contribution)... I refined it a little bit to take out redundant array counting.  I also named the variables a little differently for my own understanding.

If you want to use this exactly like shuffle(), you could modify the parameter to be passed by reference, i.e. &$array, then make sure you change the return to simply: "return;" and assign the resulting random array back to $array as such:
$array = $randArr;  (Before the return).

```
function mt_shuffle($array) {
    $randArr = [];
    $arrLength = count($array);

    // while my array is not empty I select a random position
    while (count($array)) {
        //mt_rand returns a random number between two values
        $randPos = mt_rand(0, --$arrLength);
        $randArr[] = $array[$randPos];

        /* If number of remaining elements in the array is the same as the
         * random position, take out the item in that position,
         * else use the negative offset.
         * This will prevent array_splice removing the last item.
         */
        array_splice($array, $randPos, ($randPos == $arrLength ? 1 : $randPos - $arrLength));
    }

    return $randArr;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's random just like `rand()`;

And as PHP style you don't need to seed

Answer (score 2):

```
mt_rand()
```

Generates a random number.

```
shuffle()
```

Randomizes an array.  It also generates new keys in the array rather than just rearranging the old ones.

If you want to seed in PHP you would have used `mt_strand()`.

However, since PHP 4.2.0 seeding is done automatically in PHP when you call mt_rand.

Comment: So, basically if you want to use mt_rand() as your generator you have to roll your own shuffle() function? Or if mt_rand() is already used does shuffle use that?

Answer (score 2):

**Works with associative and numeric arrays:**

```
function mt_shuffle_array($array) {
    $shuffled_array = [];
    $arr_length = count($array);

    if($arr_length < 2) {
        return $array;
    }

    while($arr_length) {
        --$arr_length;
        $rand_key = array_keys($array)[mt_rand(0, $arr_length)];

        $shuffled_array[$rand_key] = $array[$rand_key];
        unset($array[$rand_key]);
    }

    return $shuffled_array;
}

$array = [-2, -1, 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => '3', 11, 'd' => '4', 22];
$shuffled_array = mt_shuffle_array($array);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function who sort my array randomly.

```
/**
 * Build a random array
 *
 * @param mixed $array
 *
 * @return array
 */
function random_array($array) {
    $random_array = array();
    // array start by index 0
    $countArray = count($array) - 1;

    // while my array is not empty I build a random value
    while (count($array) != 0) {
        //mt_rand return a random number between two value 
        $randomValue = mt_rand(0, $countArray);
        $random_array[] = $array[$randomValue];

        // If my count of my tab is 4 and mt_rand give me the last element, 
        // array_splice will not unset the last item
        if(($randomValue + 1) == count($array)) {
            array_splice($array, $randomValue, ($randomValue - $countArray + 1));
        } else {
            array_splice($array, $randomValue, ($randomValue - $countArray));
        }

        $countArray--;
    }

    return $random_array;
}
```

It's not the best way to do that but when I've used the function shuffle, it was always returning a random array in the same order. If this could help someone, I will be happy !

Comment: You should use array_splice and update the countArray each iteration. Unset leaves gaps in the array and if you randomly pick one of the indices which you've already unset, you will add a NULL to the output array.