# Random number within range with a seed

Tags: php

I've been trying to wrap my head around solving this issue but I can't seem to find a simple solution to it.

I have a dynamic grid layout, articles are placed on the grid but have different width & height. This width & height of these different articles can change upon visiting the site but only when there is a new article added.

The issue is I have logic that uses `mt_rand` to generate random numbers within a range (to fit in the layout grid), is there a way I can pass in a seed (planning to use the newest article id) so that the random numbers are consistent until a new article is introduced? I wanted to use `mt_srand` but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to limit the random number within a range.

Thanks.

Comment: this should answer your question looks like the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694319/how-random-is-phps-shuffle-function

Comment: @Sinan, not a dupe of **that** question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating UNIQUE Random Numbers within a range - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612656/generating-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range-php)

Comment: sorry guys I totally misread mt_srand I thought it was used to seed and generate a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mt_srand() is used to set your seed and mt_rand() takes in a min and max if you want to set the range.  Basically something like:

```
mt_srand($seed);
mt_rand($min, $max);
```

**Note:** As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is now done automatically.