# generating a random no.in php

Tags: php, html, random

I am working in an application which is a online examination application. Now at first the students has to login and they will get the questions. Now what i want is when the students login then a random no. must be generated between 1 to 50. And that will extract 50 questions for him. How to generate the random number between 1 to 50 when the login is successful.

This is my html code:

```
<body>
<h3>Login Form</h3>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
  Student Username: 
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  </label>
  <p>Student Password: 
    <label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="login" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
```

Now when the login is successful then a random no. between 1 to 50 must be generated.

Comment: [mt_rand(1,50)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number within range with a seed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208141/random-number-within-range-with-a-seed) And I don't understand why include your login form? What is your real objective? How single random number can use to determine 50 questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP random string generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if i understand you, you need to use [`rand` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) or [`mt_rand` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) functions like:

```
rand(1, 50);
```

Comment: As documented here: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: Or if you want better randomness use `mt_random(min,max)`, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php, see: http://www.random.org/analysis/ for some of the problems with php's `rand`

Comment: actually i know this is a simple question but i have a lot to do after that which i am not getting to express.sorry