# PHP shuffle vs rand - which produces better randomness

Tags: php

Does any one know which of the two choices for random number generation is going to produce a better randomness:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

shuffle($array);
echo $array[0];

//// OR ////

echo rand(1,6);

?>
```

Or perhaps theres an even better option I am unaware of?

Comment: shuffle() uses the same generator as rand() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694319/how-random-is-phps-shuffle-function

Comment: I just rolled a 4 with my six-sided dice. Feel free to use that - all I ask is credit.

Comment: "Better" in what sense? It's really hard to figure out what you're looking for here.

Comment: Do what Sony does: `DEFINE('rand()', 3);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both use the same [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRNG) so their randomness is equally good/bad. Obviously a plain `rand(1,6)` is faster since it's just the math and not both the math and the array stuff. Besides that, you'd use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) if you wanted a random element from an array.

PHP also has the [mersenne twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/efaq.html) ([`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand)) which is "better" but unsuitable for cryptography (probably not relevant in your case).

If you need *true* randomness you could consider reading from `/dev/random` - but that read may block if there's no randomness available. You could also use a hardware device that gives you even better randomness based on some physical effect.

Comment: agreed, the "randomness" is going to be the same. I would look at the processing time if it were only dealing with integers. `rand()` surely would run faster.

Answer (score 1):

On most systems, seed the random number generator with a random value.  In most applications, using the low order parts of the current time (like seconds and microseconds) is a pretty good strategy.  Whether that works for you depends on the application.

On a Linux system, the program can also read a few bytes from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` to seed the random number generator.  It is a concentration of random entropy from device drivers and other hard-to-predict phenomena.

Comment: Seeding the RNG has been unnecessary on most platforms for quite some time now, and in PHP it's been unnecessary since 4.2.

Comment: @Sammitch:  Why is that?  Is it because the RNG self seeds with the time?