# How to use random () function to shuffle array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

In one interview I was asked to shuffle an associative array that has value like .

```
$card = array (
               "car"=>1,
                "bus"=>2,
                "truck"=>3,
);
```

etc.
Using a radom function that generate random digit between `0,1` ;

They asked me not to use any inbuilt PHP function .

```
input: associative array;
output: randomly sequenced associative array;
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Looks like a homework!!

Comment: @b0s3 :) Yes I have tried doing something , I will update my code though its not working yet

Comment: "They asked me not to use any inbuilt PHP function"  so write php with out php - that would be a great skill

Comment: and um if your going to put code in your profile, how about making valid?

Comment: Fetch the keys using `array_keys()`, then use Fisher-Yates shuffle on that, then rebuild the array.

Comment: @Dagon Actually, `shuffle()` wouldn't work out of the box, because it will lose the associative keys ;-)

Comment: My implementation with mt_rand better than shuffle() http://stackoverflow.com/a/43532529/960020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) doesn't handle associative arrays very well, so you'd need to shuffle the array keys and then reconstitute the array again.

I'm using the [Fisher-Yates-Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm to perform the shuffling, which is really the crux of the solution.

```
function myshuffle($arr)
{
    // extract the array keys
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
    }

    // shuffle the keys    
    for ($i = count($keys) - 1; $i >= 1; --$i) {
        $r = mt_rand(0, $i);
        if ($r != $i) {
            $tmp = $keys[$i];
            $keys[$i] = $keys[$r];
            $keys[$r] = $tmp;
        }
    }

    // reconstitute
    $result = [];
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: we can not use any array built in function

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Actually, OP said "They asked me not to use *any* inbuilt PHP function" .. that would include `rand()` though lol

Comment: so true ... so -1 :D for using foreach, count, and mt_rand LOL

Comment: Good thing `foreach` is not a built-in function ;-)

Comment: ohh my bad .. its loop, And your shuffling logic is better than mine i just created mess, didnt thought abuot that

Comment: thought it can be easily done by shuffling  key from keys array  shuffle($keys);

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yeah, the whole midsection can disappear with a simple `shuffle()` call =S

Answer (score -2):

```
    $words = array("adumbrate","antipathy","aspersion","assiduous","cacophony","conundrum");


 $rand_word_index = array_rand($words); // Get any random index from an array

        //  Original Word
 $rand_word = $words[$rand_word_index]; // Stored array value basis of random index


$shuffled = str_shuffle($rand_word); // Shuffle this value or word

echo $shuffled;
```

Comment: you can not use built in array function .. read the question carefully please

Comment: Also, this gives a string and not an array.